Why can't I link my assembly code on windows?
I'm learning assembly with nasm assembler, and I encounter troubles when linking .o file. Can't resolve this issue for days and don't understand what is wrong. Here is the code and commands:
  section .data
      hello db 'Hello, World!', 0
  
  section .text
      global _start
  
  _start:
      ; Write message to stdout
      mov eax, 4          ; sys_write
      mov ebx, 1          ; file descriptor (stdout)
      mov ecx, hello      ; message to write
      mov edx, 13         ; message length
      int 0x80            ; interrupt to make syscall
  
      ; Exit
      mov eax, 1          ; sys_exit
      xor ebx, ebx        ; return 0
      int 0x80

Assembling and linking:
nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello.o
gcc -m32 hello.o -o hello.exe

Error:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to WinMain@16'


That's a linux program. Windows has a different ABI.

yes, at first this is not windows code ( int 0x80 ) at second you not direct setup entry point, as result WinMainCRTStartup is used by default and this function call _WinMain@16. but not is _WinMain@16 in your code. so linker and say undefined reference to WinMain@16

Judging by your use of int 0x80 you are targeting Linux.
So, the [Windows] tag on the question is Red Herring.
Then you do nasm -f elf32 hello.asm -o hello.o which further indicates that you are targeting Linux.  So far so good.
But then, you do gcc -m32 hello.o -o hello.exe which targets Windows.  (.exe is a Windows thing.  There is no such thing as .exe in Linux.)
So, you have to decide: are you going to target Linux, or are you going to target Windows?  Once you decide that, write your code accordingly, and use your tools accordingly.  You cannot mix and match.
